# Android Studio complains about missing permission check for Fingerprint sensor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fingerprint-api

I have the following code-lines:

```
    FingerprintManager fm = activity.getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);
    fm.isHardwareDetected();
```

At this Point, Android Studio complains about a missing permssionCheck (checkSelfPermission).

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

However, as I understand the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html), USE_FINGERPRINT (required by [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html)) is not a "dangerous" permission and thus is granted at install time. If I suppress the AndroidStudio warning everything works fine on my test devices.
Is this a bogus warning?

Comment: "FingerprintSensor is not a "dangerous" permission" -- I do not know what "FingerprintSensor" is. [`USE_FINGERPRINT` is a permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_FINGERPRINT). That permission is `normal`, and so if that is what you are referring to, I agree that Android Studio should not be complaining about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This clearly seems to be an AndroidStudio bug. I have added

```
//noinspection MissingPermission
```

to supress this warning, and there are no negative consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the permission to your Manifest file already? You don't need to request the permission at runtime, but you still need to have the manifest entry.

Comment: Yes, I have the permission in the manifest, otherwise it would not work at all.